# MySqlException: Unable to Connect to any of specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using default port (3306) of mySQL

and my connecting string is like

`Server=184.27.45.87;Database=xxxxx;Uid=xxxxx;Pwd=yyyyy`

Still I am getting error at line

`con.Open()`

getting exception

`MySqlException: Unable to Connect to any of specified MySQL hosts`

stack trace

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' oc7curred in mscorlib.dll

An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

The thread 0x1944 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.DLL
```

Comment: What is the issue? Could you spend your time to fit your question?

Comment: How do you expect to answer this question man, what is the error or exception that you are seeing, what is your goal? and how did you conclude that the prob is in connection string?

Comment: Can post the stack trace ? Are you able to `telnet` the server on the port specified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you should use `uid` instead of `User ID` of the SQL query string is as follows:

```
server=$servername$;database=$databasename$;uid=$username$;password=$password$;
```

Where `$servername$` is the name of the machine where your MySQL Server is running (localhost if it's on your own machine) and `$databasename$` the name of your database (or catalog, as some call it), `$username$` a user which is allowed to access the database you selected and `$password$` the password of the user.

Example:

```
    //create a MySQL connection with a query string
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=cs;uid=root;password=abcdaaa");

    //open the connection
    connection.Open();

    //close the connection
    connection.Close();
```

Comment: Doesn't the format of the connection string depend on the driver?

Comment: @Cularis, The error is in the `Connection String` : `uid` should be used instead of `User ID` : http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Comment: Scroll down and you will see other connection strings that fit @Ankits format. He never said what driver he used.

Comment: What I am guessing that he would probably be using the default .NET driver for MySQL :)

Comment: Actually how to know which default .net driver I am using? pls reply thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when MySqlConnector trying to connecting using IPV6. Same error. 
You need to update your driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My MySQL server was on a remote machine and by default it does not accept remote connections. I had to explictly add my machine's IP address to its list of accepted IPs.